# Grails WEB-INF accessible from Deployed app

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, web-inf

In grails application, one can access the WEB-INF contents including all the .gsp content as well as .class file when deployed.

I am  using grails 2.3.5 and deploying the war in the tomcat 7.

You can access the files using

http://mydomain.com/static/WEB-INF/web.xml
http://mydomain.com/static/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/anyview.gsp
http://mydomain.com/static/WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties
http://mydomain.com/static/WEB-INF/classes/anyclass.class

Can I disable access to these url in grails?

Comment: What is your mapping for /static URL? That should be fixed.

Comment: You mean on the UrlMappings.groovy? I tried putting "/static/WEB-INF/**"(view:"/error"), but the result was same

Comment: No servlet container should ever let you see the contents of files under WEB-INF. What server are you using?

Comment: I am using default plugin provided by grails  build ":tomcat:7.0.50". Also deploying on the tomcat 7.0.39 on the production environment has the same issue

Comment: I doubt you have a /static mapping in your web.xml. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In grails by default, there is resources plugin. And it maps all the resources such as css, js, images, WEB-INF, plugins and META-INF which you will find when you extract war file.

You need to include following line in your config.groovy to include just css, js and images in static resources.

```
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/images/**','/js/**','/css/**']
```

You can also use :

`grails.resources.adhoc.excludes = ['/WEB-INF/**']`

to exclude only WEB-INF.

I don't know whether I should say for more information or just for information. Anyway you can also find some information of this in [documentation of resources plugin in configuration part](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html) which has title

> Controlling the includes and excludes of the adhoc filter: grails.resources.adhoc.includes/excludes